# Logical simplification clarification

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

My question is "Using Logical simplification, prove that the following is a tautology, contradiction or neither."

$p \land ((\lnot p \lor q)\land \lnot q)$

My logic is probably wrong but this is what I attempted:

Removing the brackets to get to this

$(p \land \lnot p) \lor (q\land \lnot q)$

then using negation laws this evaluates to:

$(F) \lor (F) $

proving that this is a contradiction as every outcome is false.

Is there anything stopping me from applying the logic I used in the first step? If not what is the correct approach to doing this?

**EDIT 1**

---

so using absorption as mentioned below I got to this:

$ p \land ((\lnot p \lor q)\land \lnot q)$

$ p \land (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$

then using associative getting this

$(p \land \lnot p)\land \lnot q$

$(F) \land \lnot q$

which doesn't prove if it is a tautology, contradiction or neither

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You cannot just remove brackets.  That would be like saying $2\cdot((3+4)\cdot 1) = (2\cdot 3)+(4\cdot 1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the distributive properties.  Or distributes over And :

$$(a \land b) \lor c \equiv (a \lor c) \land (b \lor c)$$

and And distributes over Or :

$$(a \lor b) \land c \equiv (a \land c) \lor (b \land c)$$

So:

$$P \land (\underbrace{(\lnot P \lor Q) \land \lnot Q}_\text{Distr. And})$$

$$\underbrace{P \land (\overbrace{(\lnot P \land Q) \lor (Q \land \lnot Q)}^\text{To this})}_\text{Commute And}$$

$$\underbrace{((\lnot P \land Q) \lor (Q \land \lnot Q)) \land P}_\text{Distr. And}$$

$$((\lnot P \land Q) \land P) \lor ((Q \land \lnot Q) \land P)$$

Then just finish it up.  This is btw just a symbolic way of doing truth tables.

Comment: Thanks, I can do truth tables, but in this instance I wasn't allowed to use truth tables, and I struggle a bit applying the laws to the statements

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just remove brackets *unless* the operations are associative.   That's not the case here.

The rule you want is "absorption": $$(\psi\vee\neg\phi)\wedge\phi~=~\psi\wedge\phi$$

Comment: You're quite right about the brackets! ... but what you have there is Reduction ... Absorption is $$(\psi\vee\phi)\wedge\phi~=\phi$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very handy equivalence rule that unfortunately many texts don't provide you outright:

**Reduction**

$$\neg P \land (P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \land Q$$

The intuitive idea here is that (from left to right) given $\neg P$, the term $P \lor Q$ can be 'reduced' to just $Q$.  But obviously you can go from right to left as well, so this is an equivalence. And of course you also have its dual:

$$\neg P \lor (P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor Q$$

Applied to your statement:

$$P \land ((\neg P \lor Q) \land \neg Q) \Leftrightarrow P \land (\neg P \land \neg Q) \Leftrightarrow (P \land \neg P) \land \neg Q \Leftrightarrow \bot \land \neg Q \Leftrightarrow \bot$$

So ... it's a contradiction!